# SELECT a record using length of string as a condition. Tried LEN(), LENGTH(), and CHAR_LENGTH

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Ok so Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to select items in my database that have more than just a single character saved in the scripts_assigned field, along with 2 other conditions (see code below).
Instead of getting the 4000 items I need it to get, it pretty much ignores the Length condition so I end up with the script going by the other two conditions giving me 17k records.

```
 $getSale = $connection->prepare("SELECT `script_assigned` FROM `transactions` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH('script_assigned') >  ? AND `ClientDealerID` = ? AND `file_type` = ?");
    $getSale->execute(array(1,"STORE","SL"));
    $gotSale = $getSale->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $getSale = null; //Release
    print_r($gotSale);
```

Another thing I tried that works in the SQL console but not in my script for some reason is this (see code below).

```
$getSale = $connection->prepare("SELECT `script_assigned` FROM `transactions` WHERE `script_assigned` >  ? AND `ClientDealerID` = ? AND `file_type` = ?");
        $getSale->execute(array(1,"STORE","SL"));
        $gotSale = $getSale->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $getSale = null; //Release
        print_r($gotSale);
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the column names.  I vote to close such questions as a typographical error.

Comment: Sorry you are right I did not notice that, I thought I removed that while doing something I was trying since it still did not work. I edited my post but still by removing the quotes it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
LENGTH(script_assigned) > 0
```

it should work. However, you may get the records that have script_assigned set to a sequence of white space characters. To deal with that

```
LENGTH(TRIM(script_assigned)) > 0
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you!